# Biblatex: Suppress shorthand in a selection of documents

Tags: biblatex

My problem is this: I use one biblatex-file as a source for a number of documents. In the biblatex-file I used `shorthand` in every entry. The problem is that in some documents I need to cite the references fully rather than the short form. My question: Is there something a command that I could add to my preamble in order to suppress the shorthand entry and to get full title output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you simply want to suppress the use of shorthands in citation commands for all entries, adding

```
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{shorthand}}
```

to the preamble should do. If you have more specific requirements, please add a MWE to your question.

Answer (score 2):

To completely clear the `shorthand` field use

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=shorthand, null]
    }
  }
}
```

This also works for numeric styles, where the shorthand is used instead of numeric labels, and enables proper disambiguation for `authoryear` styles.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is to remove display of shorthands in the reference list, use:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{shorthand}}
```

(I don't quite get the question as to whether shorthands are to be removed from citation keys or from reference list. Combining it with Lockstep's answer this is useful.)

Comment: That will remove the `shortand`s in the bibliography. With some styles the `shorthand` it not used in the bibliography anyway.

Comment: Yeah thanks, i clarified in the answer: I think sometimes one wants to combine both to remove shorthands from citekeys and reflist.

Comment: In that case one should probably use a source mapping that removes the field completely to avoid problems with disambiguation features.

Comment: Maybe you would like to post this as an answer? Cause I get the original question the way that shorthands are to be completely removed from the document. :)

Comment: I guess the OP got what he needed, but on the off chance that someone is interested in a full removal of `shorthand` I have added an answer.