# Can I suppress \nameaddon in Footnotes without using \shortcite in Biblatex-Chicago?

Tags: biblatex, biber, chicago-style

I am using the `nameaddon` field to include death dates of certain authors in my bibliography.  This is working well in the bibliography at the end, but doesn't always give the results I want in the footnotes.  Is there an option to suppress the `nameaddon` in a footnote citation without resorting to `\shortcite`?
I'm using Biber backend.

Comment: `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{nameaddon}}`?

Comment: Since in [a follow-up question of yours](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244673/35864) you mention that the above worked for you, I'm going to vote to close as a duplicate of [Biblatex: Suppress shorthand in a selection of documents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57041/35864), the one difference being that you have to exchange `shorthand` for `nameaddon`.