# How do I suppress the repetition of \nameaddon information in a biblatex-chicago bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, biber, chicago-style

I am using the `nameaddon` field to include death dates of certain authors in my bibliography (biblatex-chicago with Biber backend). Thanks to @moewe I am using `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{nameaddon}}` to suppress this information in the footnotes.  As a follow on question:

If my bibliography contains multiple works from the same author, the `nameaddon` information is repeated for each of his works in the bibliography.  I only need the `nameaddon` info in the first entry.

Related to this, is there a way to change the standard square brackets in the bibliography to parentheses?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes,isbn=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A01,
    author = {Author, A.},
    year = {2001},
    nameaddon = {d. 243/857--8},
    title = {Alpha},
}
@book{B02,
    author = {Author, A.},
    year = {2002},
    nameaddon = {d. 243/857--8},
    title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
    author = {Cuthor, C.},
    year = {2003},
    title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}


Some text \autocite{A01}.

Some text \autocite{B02}.

Some text \autocite{B02}.

Some text \autocite{C03}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use an approach similar to the dashing macro

```
\makeatletter
\let\bbx@na@lasthash\undefined
\newbibmacro*{nameaddon}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\bbx@na@lasthash}
    {}
    {\printfield{nameaddon}}%
  \iffieldundef{nameaddon}
    {}  
    {\savefield{namehash}{\bbx@na@lasthash}}%
}
\makeatother
```

We then only need to make the drivers use that macro, because we have a bare `\printfield{nameaddon}` in the drivers, we need to patch all drivers manually with [`xpatch`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch).

```
\newcommand*\patchnameaddon[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\printfield{nameaddon}}
    {\usebibmacro{nameaddon}}
    {}{\typeout{biblatex warning: failed to patch nameaddon in driver #1}}}
```

And then for each entry type you want to use this

```
\patchnameaddon{book}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes,isbn=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A01,
    author = {Author, A.},
    year = {2001},
    nameaddon = {d. 243/857--8},
    title = {Alpha},
}
@book{B02,
    author = {Author, A.},
    year = {2002},
    nameaddon = {d. 243/857--8},
    title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
    author = {Cuthor, C.},
    year = {2003},
    title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand*\patchnameaddon[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\printfield{nameaddon}}
    {\usebibmacro{nameaddon}}
    {}{\typeout{biblatex warning: failed to patch nameaddon in driver #1}}}

\makeatletter
\let\bbx@na@lasthash\undefined
\newbibmacro*{nameaddon}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\bbx@na@lasthash}
    {}
    {\printfield{nameaddon}}%
  \iffieldundef{nameaddon}
    {}  
    {\savefield{namehash}{\bbx@na@lasthash}}%
}
\makeatother

\patchnameaddon{book}

\begin{document}
Some text \autocite{A01}.

Some text \autocite{B02}.

Some text \autocite{B02}.

Some text \autocite{C03}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]